# Get resolution and whether right/left looking from sentinel metadata

Tags: remote-sensing, satellite, sentinel-1, esa

Is it possible in `Sentinel hub` products to know the `resolution` of the product and whether the `SAR` was `right` or `left` looking at the scene?

I know that it's possible to know if the `SAR` was operating in a `descending` or `ascending` mode from the `/annotation/*.xml` files (from the `...' value), but I couldn't find the aforementioned parameters inside those files!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The look direction of the C-SAR instrument is [right](https://sentinel.esa.int/web/sentinel/sentinel-1-sar-wiki/-/wiki/Sentinel%20One/Instrument).

The resolution as well as the pixel spacing depends on the product and the acquisition mode. They can range from 1.7m x 4.3 for Level 1 SLC SM to 52m by 51m for Level 1 GRD WV. ESA provides a [list of all resolutions and pixel spacings for Sentinel-1 products](https://sentinel.esa.int/web/sentinel/user-guides/sentinel-1-sar/resolutions).